# Page not found (404 Error) even if the page exists?

Tags: 404-error

So I created a page called test.mydomain.com/hello and when I try to access it, it gives me a 404 error. I tried switching my permalink structure to default and back to post name to see if this was the error, but it's not. In the page editor, I can see that it's the good permalink and when I click on view page, it still gives me a 404 error. Also my htacess is just the default htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPresss
```

Any ideas arre greatly appreciated!!

Comment: It is hard to tell where this is going wrong. Is there an otherwise working WordPress installation at `test.mydomain.com`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. There is a wordpress intallation at test.mydomain.com/wordpress. The homepage is working as well as the posts, just not the pages :/.

Comment: OK. There is a WordPress site here: `test.mydomain.com/wordpress`. But you are talking about a page here: `test.mydomain.com/hello`. What is the connection? Is this supposed to be a non-WordPress page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pages 404 in wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116104/pages-404-in-wordpress)

Comment: No it is a wordpress page. I created a page in the wordpress admin and gave it the title hello. The permalink that was given by wordpress to this page is test.mydomain.com/hello.

Comment: Something is odd. Do your other WordPress pages show up at `test.mydomain.com/pagename`?

Comment: No all my pages give the 404 error, unlike my homepage and posts.

Comment: It sucks I can't use bounty right now... I'm really stucked.

Answer (score 4):

Change your current permalink structure to the WordPress Default Permalink structure and then again change it back to your current permalink structure. Hope it will work!

If not then clear your browser cache and use Wp [Super Cache plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) to clear WordPress Cache. and then open the URL `test.mydomain.com/wordpress/hello/`

Comment: This. OP's problem is that he thinks that he should visit `test.mydomain.com/hello/` rather than `test.mydomain.com/wordpress/hello/`

Comment: Not really! I can access to every posts like this test.mydomain.com/postname. I wanted to put the wordpress installation in a different folder, but I did that: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Answer (score 0):

I was modifying the main query in pre_get_posts...

Comment: If this is the solution then this question is almost certainly too localized but it would help if you could elaborate on this answer.

Comment: I was modifying the main query of all request into some custom post types, so it was never using the page.php template. When I was typing test.mydomain.com/pageName, it was actually searching for test.mydomain.com/customPostType/pageName, which resulted in a 404 error.