# whats is the perfect configuration to .htaccess for permalinks?

Tags: permalinks

I have wordpress site with the normal url, when i try change this to permalinks, wordpress says 404 not found in the other pages that not is the home.

after of search in the codex, i found that the `.htaccess` file needed the 666 permissions, but my site still the errors

My configuration for the `.htaccess` is :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: My guess: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/142733/21376

Comment: How i do to set AllowOverride in my .htaccess ?

Comment: You don't set it in `.htaccess`. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116637/21376  You do know the site has a "search" function, right?